# How to link keyboard press to action

Tags: keyboard, elm

I'm getting the hang of Elm but I keep struggling with signals and keyboard presses. The code below is an example of the start-app package. I would like to have that when I press the spacebar that the counter is incremented. How is this done in the example below?

```
import Html exposing (div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import StartApp.Simple as StartApp


main =
  StartApp.start { model = model, view = view, update = update }


model = 0


view address model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick address Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]


type Action = Increment | Decrement


update action model =
  case action of
    Increment -> model + 1
    Decrement -> model - 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use regular [`StartApp`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/start-app/latest/StartApp) rather than `StartApp.Simple` because it provides the means to use Effects and Tasks.

The `Action` needs a `NoOp` constructor to allow our view to remain unchanged when a key press is not the spacebar.

Then you'll need a function which maps the `Keyboard.presses` value to an `Action`. Here's the updated code:

```elm
import Html exposing (div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import StartApp
import Effects exposing (Never)
import Task 
import Keyboard
import Char

app =
  StartApp.start
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , inputs = [ Signal.map spaceToInc Keyboard.presses ]
    }

main =
  app.html

type alias Model = Int

init =
  (0, Effects.none)

view address model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick address Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]

type Action
  = Increment
  | Decrement
  | NoOp

update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp -> (model, Effects.none)
    Increment -> (model + 1, Effects.none)
    Decrement -> (model - 1, Effects.none)

spaceToInc : Int -> Action
spaceToInc keyCode =
  case (Char.fromCode keyCode) of
    ' ' -> Increment
    _ -> NoOp

port tasks : Signal (Task.Task Never ())
port tasks =
  app.tasks
```

Comment: I have an additional question. How would I do this if I wanted to increment if I press two buttons at the same time. I can't use `Keyboard.presses` anymore because you can't check if they are pressed at the same time.

Comment: Take a look at [`Keyboard.keysDown`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Keyboard#keysDown). That signal gives you a `Set` of all keys currently down. You may run into problems if you're trying to determine a key press rather than a continuously held-down key, but since you'll get a new signal when one of the keys is let up, perhaps it's what you're after.